# Does anyone know how to use the MediaSyncEvent to sync playback and capture?

Tags: android, audio, speex, aec

Reference doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaSyncEvent.html

As I'm working on AEC (Acoustic Echo Cancellation), using the Speex library

```
speex_echo_cancellation();
```

I found that the received audio data in speaker thread (playback) and recorded audio data in microphone thread (capture), they are needed to be sync, but I failed to do so. I wonder MediaSyncEvent would help on this?

If not, anyone know how to make the audio data of playback and capture be sync?